# Data Execution Preventing Popup

Tags: windows-xp, print-spooler, dep, data-execution-prevention

After uninstalling a couple print drivers and restarting my system, I got this weird Data Execution Prevention popup window (see attachment). It's weird because it states that it shut down the Microsoft Spooler SubSystem App, which kept crashing, and was why I uninstalled the print drivers. What is going on with this message, and what should I do about it? Thanks.

[image: DEP Popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the print drivers you uninstalled were buggy (causing the crashes), and after uninstallation they left "bits" of themselves on your system, screwing up the print spooler. If the remaining fragments of the print drivers caused the spooler to try to execute a part of RAM marked as "data" this would cause the error you saw.

It's also possible that a Registry key is telling the spooler to read the printer driver from a location that doesn't exist any more.

Does the problem persist across multiple boots? Do you have to try to print to make it happen?

A Repair Installation of XP might fix this, if you have a full XP install disk (and not OEM restore disks).

Comment: Accepted for now because it is the best answer.  However, my DEP problems seem to have gone away.  I was able to get the print driver uninstalled and do a clean install.

Answer (score -1):

The DEP program has a set of programs that it disallow.

You can manage it in the DEP settings somewhere within the "System" control panel. I don't remember my old XP GUI very well :P.
You can authorise the program, or shut off the DEP system. I don't really know the implications of doing so regarding security, but it used to bother me a lot a long time ago.